# Can you start function definition with a typeclass?

Tags: haskell

In this [tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses), at the very bottom, the author provides a function type of:

```
(Num b) => length :: [a] -> b
```

So you can see that it begins with typeclass "Num b" (at least that's what I think it is). But when I try to define something like:

```
(Integral a) => lucky :: a -> String
```

I get an error:

> parse error on input `=>'

Who is wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tutorial is wrong, the type class has to come after the `::`, the type signature ought to be `length :: Num b => [a] -> b`.

The syntax is specified in the language report, section 10.5 [context free syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5), the pertinent production is *gendecl*.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find this "rule"? Thanks!

Comment: @drozzy: If you want something official, there's the language definition. More pragmatically, you'll see that every place that explains class constraints shows it like this, modulo typos (which explains the snippet you cite). Look at the rest of Learn You a Haskell (e.g. the `Typeclass 101` section of the very same page), for instance.

Comment: @drozzy In the language report, I added a link to the pertinent part to my answer. The report is fairly accessible, so I advise reading it relatively early. Check it out and read a bit of it every now and then until you feel you can take the whole thing, then read it from start to finish.

Comment: I sent Miran an email about the typo (via the contact info listed at http://learnyouahaskell.com/faq )

Comment: Miran responded; he vaguely mentioned an updated version and said he would fix this along with "all sorts of fixes". :)